# How can I create a frame which holds an "empty" Message widget at a certain size

Tags: python, tkinter

My problem with this code is that the text box that appears when you hover over a button resizes the entire window. What I want is for this frame to have the same size as the Text field which will place the information there.

```
import tkinter
import re
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk, filedialog
from ctypes import windll
from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText


class MainApp(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        #self.geometry("500x300")
        self.title("My Bioinformatics Toolbox")

        def fasta_button_hover(hover):
            instructions_field.config(text="This function will allow the user to open, "
                                       "read and see the contents of a .FASTA file. It "
                                       "will also allow the user to save their own sequence "
                                       "as a FASTA file")

        def fasta_button_leave(hover):
                instructions_field.config(text="")

        # Create the menu bar
        menu_bar = tkinter.Menu(self)
        file_menu = tkinter.Menu(menu_bar, tearoff=0)

        # The File cascade in the menu bar
        menu_bar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=file_menu)
        file_menu.add_command(label="Exit", command=self.destroy)

        self.config(menu=menu_bar)

        # Create the buttons frame
        button_frame = ttk.Frame(self)
        #button_frame.configure(height=button_frame["height"], width=button_frame["width"])
        #button_frame.grid_propagate(0)
        button_frame.pack(side=LEFT)

        # Create the text field frame
        text_frame = ttk.Frame(self, width=500)
        text_frame.pack(side=RIGHT)

        # Create the instructions field
        instructions_field = Message(text_frame, width=300)
        instructions_field.grid(column=0, row=0)

        # Create the buttons
        fasta_button = ttk.Button(button_frame, text="Read FASTA", width=12)
        fasta_button.bind("<Enter>", fasta_button_hover)
        fasta_button.bind("<Leave>", fasta_button_leave)
        fasta_button.grid(column=0, row=0)

        dna_to_rna_button = ttk.Button(button_frame, text="DNA to RNA", width=12)
        dna_to_rna_button.grid(column=0, row=1)

        example_button = ttk.Button(button_frame, text="Example", width=12)
        example_button.grid(column=0, row=2)

        example_button2 = ttk.Button(button_frame, text="Example2", width=12)
        example_button2.grid(column=0, row=3)

        example_button3 = ttk.Button(button_frame, text="Example3", width=12)
        example_button3.grid(column=0, row=4)

        # A separator line ("rowspan" is set to a safe number of rows)
        button_separator = ttk.Separator(button_frame, orient="vertical")
        button_separator.grid(column=1, row=0, rowspan=100, sticky="ns")

# Fix for windows DPI scaling
windll.shcore.SetProcessDpiAwareness(1)

app = MainApp()
app.mainloop()
```

I want my window to have this size [full size app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wYt2M.png) at all time, but when I'm not hovering it has this size [small puny app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6QtKn.png)

My guess is that I'm missing something from the `text_frame`, but I can't figure it out...

Edit to update indentation

Comment: Please correct the indentation

Comment: Also you aren't using classes correctly. Please look at some python object oriented tutorials.

Comment: all of the indented code after `# Create the menu bar` needs to be inside `__init__`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This amendment to your code seems to achieve this:

```python
# Create the instructions field
instructions_field = ttk.Label(text_frame, width=50, wraplength=300)
instructions_field.grid(column=0, row=0)
```

The changes made:

- Replaced the `Message` widget with a `Label` widget
- Set both the `width` and `wraplength` keyword arguments in the Label
- Manually adjusted the wraplength (taken as a number of pixels before wrapping) to fit all of the text inside the widget

It is arguably not the most elegant solution but a working and reliable one nonetheless

Note: The width keyword argument in the Label is taken as a number of characters wide

Comment: Thank you! This seems to work as I want it to! Non I'll get to figuring out how I can get the wraplenght in characters instead of pixels to make this work on different resolution displays :)